# 'No such module XCTest' while trying to create a unit test class and importing 'XCTest'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, compiler-warnings

I'm just starting with learning Unit testing. I didn't check the 'Include tests' check box while creating the project. When I tried to create a Unit Test Case class by myself, I received a warning in the line where XCTest is imported saying 'No such module XCTest'.

I created a file with class Unit Test Case class under a folder that I made. Inside which i got the warning.

Answer (score 1):

It's missing target to the application. To add target,
[You can find add target in the Editor of Menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIzQK.png)

After that select,
[Unit testing bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoQwv.png)

This will create a file with a class that conforms to XCTestCase class.
You will be able to find the required screenshots on clicking the hyperlink texts.

(or)

Add

```
@testable import (App Name)
```

after the

```
import XCTest
```

line to silence this warning.